# Show / Hide button base on column value

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, datatables

I have a Grid View where i have 2 columns (FOOD and OPERATIONS). In FOOD column I am showing my menu. In OPERATIONS column, I have 2 buttons (*DELETE* and *EDIT*).
What I want is if FOOD is "HAMBURGER" I want the two buttons to be visible, otherwise I want to hide them.
[Here is the demonstration of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peMTO.jpg)

I have tried this code in jQuery. But I don't think if the condition implementation is correct.

```js
Menu = $('#tblMenu').DataTable({
        columns: [
            { "data": "FOOD", responsivePriority: 1, "searchable": true },
            {
                "data": null,
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    btn = '<div class="d-flex">';
                    btn += '<a class="btn btn-info" href="/editMenu?id=' + row.idOrder + '\">EDIT</a>';
                    btn += '<a class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteMenu" href="/deleteMenu?id=' + row.idOrder + '\">DELETE</a>';
                    
                    //Condition
                    if (data.find("FOOD") != "HAMBURGER") {
                        /*btn +=*/ $('<a class="btn btn-info" href="/editMenu?id=' + row.idOrder + '\">EDIT</a>').hide();
                        $('<a class="btn btn-danger"  href="/deleteMenu?id=' + row.idOrder + '\">DELETE</a>').hide();
                    } else {
                        $('<a class="btn btn-info" href="/editMenu?id=' + row.idOrder + '\">EDIT</a>').show();
                        $('<a class="btn btn-danger"  href="/deleteMenu?id=' + row.idOrder + '\">DELETE</a>').show();
                    }

                    btn += '</div>';
                    return btn;
                }, 
            }
        ]
    });
    
//HTML
<table class="table align-middle table-bordered text-center w-100" style="font-size:75%; " id="tblMenu">
    <thead class="table-primary">
        <tr>
            <th class="align-middle">FOOD</th>
            <th class="align-middle">OPERATIONS</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show us more of your code?

Comment: In order to help we would need the HTML of the grid view with the two columns.

Comment: the question changed substantially since its first iteration to the point that my answer doesn't fit anymore...you are doing a mess in your code.. you are creating elements from scratch that you show/hide without adding them to the dom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) is being used as well as [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/). I assumed that OP has BS4 since DataTables has yet to have a stylesheet for BS5. See **Figure I** for the list of external files loaded for the example.

**Figure I**

- bootstrap.min.css v4.6.1
- dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css v1.10.21
- jquery.min.js v3.6.1
- popper.min.js v1.16.1
- bootstrap.bundle.min.js v4.6.1
- jquery.dataTables.min.js v1.10.21

In the `dataTable()` plugin, [`columnDefs`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) parameter and [`render: function()`](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers) property were used to resolve the problem. See **Figure II**.

**Figure II**

```js
{
  targets: 1, // This is rendering buttons in the second column
  data: null, // This uses the whole source (dataSet)
  render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
    /**
     * If data.item (OP: data.FOOD) is not "CONFIGURABLE" (OP: "HAMBURGER")...
     * >status< = "hidden" otherwise it's = "" (nothing)
     */
    let status = data.item !== "CONFIGURABLE" ? "hidden" : "";
    /**
     * Only a single string is needed. Note that >status< is a class 
     * (see CSS in example). It's important that the "hidden" class is
     * added to your CSS exactly how it is in the example CSS. BS styles
     * are difficult to override so if changed it may not work.
     */
    const btn = `
      <div class="btn-group ${status}">
        <a href="/editMenu?id=${row.idOrder}" class="btn btn-info">EDIT</a>
        <a href="/deleteMenu?id=${row.idOrder}" class="btn btn-danger">DELETE</a>
      </div>`;
      return btn;
    }
  }
```

```js
const dataSet = [{item:0, config:""}, {item:"CONFIGURABLE", config:""},{item:2, config:""},{item:"CONFIGURABLE", config:""},{item:4, config:""},{item:5, config:""},{item:"CONFIGURABLE", config:""},{item:7, config:""},{item:"CONFIGURABLE", config:""},{item:8, config:""},{item:9, config:""},{item:"CONFIGURABLE", config:""}];

const Menu = $('#tblMenu').DataTable({
  data: dataSet,
  columns: [{
    title: "Item"
  }, {
    title: ""
  }],
  columnDefs: [{
      targets: 0,
      data: "item"
    },
    {
      targets: 1,
      data: null,
      render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
        let status = data.item !== "CONFIGURABLE" ? "hidden" : "";
        const btn = `
          <div class="btn-group ${status}">
            <a href="/editMenu?id=${row.idOrder}" class="btn btn-info">EDIT</a>
            <a href="/deleteMenu?id=${row.idOrder}" class="btn btn-danger">DELETE</a>
          </div>`;
        return btn;
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
.btn-group.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style></style>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="container">
    <section class="row">
      <div class="col mt-5">
        <table id="tblMenu" class="table align-middle table-bordered text-center w-100" style="font-size:75%;">
          <thead class="table-primary">
            <tr>
              <th class="align-middle"></th>
              <th class="align-middle"></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

  <script></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question was changed few moments after I finished crafting this demo. So this answer doesn't perfectly fit the scenario with the datatables.net but yet it gives hints on a strategy you could implement.

In your latest code you are trying to evaluate a condition based on the input data and crafting some elements on the fly to fill the table.

You could yet have a second column containing the buttons on each single row but just show/hide that cell based on the existence of a given class in that row.

Here on document ready I'm looping through all the table rows and if the value `Hamburger` is found on the first cell, to the whole rows we add the class `enabled`. Such condition will trigger the css rule styling that cell as visible opposed to hidden.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  //for each row in the table
  $('table.foods > tbody > tr').each((i,row)=>{
    //grabs the text value from the first cell in the row,
    const foodValue = $(row).find('td:first-child').text();    
    //and if it's hamburger,
    if(foodValue == 'Hamburger'){
      //adds the class enabled to the row
      $(row).addClass('enabled');
    }      
  });
});
```

```css
/**************************************************************
 * Styles to show/hide rows having/not having the enabled class
 **************************************************************/

table.foods > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) {
  visibility: hidden;
}

table.foods > tbody > tr.enabled > td:nth-child(2) {
  visibility: visible;
}

/**************************************************************
 * Styles for better presentation
 **************************************************************/

table.foods {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

table.foods th {
  text-align: center;
}

table.foods td,
table.foods th {
  border: solid 2px black;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.action {
  border: solid 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  background: white;
}

.edit {
  border-color: red;
  color: red;
}

.delete {
  border-color: blue;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="foods">
  <thead>
    <th>FOOD</th>
    <th>DRINK</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Hamburger</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="action edit">EDIT</button>
        <button type="button" class="action delete">DELETE</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pasta</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="action edit">EDIT</button>
        <button type="button" class="action delete">DELETE</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pizza</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="action edit">EDIT</button>
        <button type="button" class="action delete">DELETE</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you show us more of your code? You are using jQuery here,

```
//Sets your ready function    
$(document).ready(function () {

                $("#Delete").click(function () {

                    $("a").hide(); //Selecting the <a> and hiding it on click
                });
                $("#show").click(function () {
                    $("a").show();//Selecting the <a> and showing it on click



                });
            });
```

Please update more on your question of what you are trying to achieve, you are currently select to all instance of  element, not though, use

```
$("#a").show(); // ID based
$(".a").show(); //Selecting with class names
```

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer